# Problems to deploy program with Anchor 0.28.0 to localnet

Tags: anchor, deploy, localnet

I am upgrading my programs to anchor 0.28.0 but I am not able to deploy anymore.
The transactions do not finalize. (devnet works fine)

[image]

These are my versions:

```
 solana --version
solana-cli 1.16.0 (src:e0fcdbb0; feat:2891131721, client:SolanaLabs)
 rustc --version
rustc 1.68.2 (9eb3afe9e 2023-03-27)
 anchor --version
anchor-cli 0.28.0
```

Anchor test works, but deploying to my solana-test-validator does not.
Any ideas? Is there any logs for the deploy?

Update: Now that i have updated CLI to 1.16.0 i get this error when i try to build:

```
program % anchor build                                                    
error: not a directory: '/Users/***/.local/share/solana/install/releases/1.16.0/solana-release/bin/sdk/sbf/dependencies/platform-tools/rust/bin'
```

Answer (score 4):

So the problem with not being able to build was that my platform tools folder was for some reason linked to an old version in /Users/***/.cache/solana/v1.37 So i deleted all these cached versions and now building works again.

The problem with not being able to deploy was that the validator state was started with the cli version 1.14.17 and then I started it again with cli version 1.16.0 which broke it.
Starting the validator with

```
solana-test-validator -reset
```

fixed it.